# Send an image from Python to QML using the PyQt5/PySide2 library:

Tags: python, image, pyqt, qml, pyside2

I want to send an image from Python to QML using the PyQt5 library, I have tried QQuickImageProvider but the code is not working, Is there another way to do that, Also, if it was in PySide2 library, it would be better.

Script python using PyQT5:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QCoreApplication, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickImageProvider

class ImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(QQuickImageProvider.Pixmap)
        self._image = QPixmap()

    def requestPixmap(self, id: str, size: QSize, requestedSize: QSize):
        return self._image

    def setImage(self, image: QPixmap):
        self._image = image

QtCore.qInstallMessageHandler(qt_message_handler)

app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

qml_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'image.qml')
qml_engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()


imageProvider = ImageProvider()

qml_engine.addImageProvider("imageProvider", imageProvider)

qml_engine.load(qml_file)

imageProvider.setImage(QPixmap("image.png"))

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

code QML :

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtMultimedia 5.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("Camera Example")
    color: "black"
    Image {
        id: image
        source: "image://imageProvider/image"
        width: 300
        height: 300
    }
}
```

Error :

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
file:///C:/Users/MonPc/Desktop/image.qml:2:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtMultimedia": Cannot load library C:\Users\MonPc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5\qml\QtMultimedia\declarative_multimedia.dll: Le module sp�cifi� est introuvable.
QPlatformPixmap: QGuiApplication required
```